# Arguments are not identified correctly

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm currently working with rtk thunks. But I got the following problem: I dispatch the extra reducer like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     useAppDispatch(getUserAccessToken())
   }, []);
```

But my Typescript linter marks this error:

[image: Linter Results]

This is my thunk definition:

```
export const getUserAccessToken = createAsyncThunk(
 "process/getAccessToken",
  async  (connectionString: string) => {
   const service = new WebPubSubServiceClient(CONNECTION_STRING, hub);
   const token = await service.getClientAccessToken();
  return token.url;
 }
 ) ;
```

Is my environment broken?

Comment: The error message is clear, you need to pass a `arg` parameter to `getUserAccessToken` function

Comment: Normally you also do `const dispatch = useAppDispatch()` and then use `dispatch`, haven't seen the hook used directly like that.